# Camera access for iMessage extension on real device

Tags: ios10, xcode8, imessage

Guys from Apple who talked in 2 sessions dedicated to **iMessage app and Stickers** showed few demos all using iOS Simulator, but as we know it doesn't emulate camera features. When trying to install iMessage extension on real device it just opens iMessage app with latest received message without being able to tap on "Message App Store" button. I'm interested in testing my extension on real device because it's using device camera, but couldn't make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug. After updating device to iOS 10 beta 4 and Xcode to version 8 beta 4, the extension is installed and running on device.